# MUI Two Object literals in label for checkbox

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am using MUI.
I have checkboxes for which I would like to have a label consisting of two object literals. This is my `FormGroup`.

```
<FormGroup>
  {data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <FormControlLabel
        key={index}
        control={<Checkbox />}
        // I need {item.title} (item.value) here
        label={item.title}
        name={item.title}
        value={item.title}
        onChange={() => handleChange(index)}
        disabled={disabledItems[index]}
        checked={checkedItems[index]}
        color="default"
      />
    )
  })}
</FormGroup>
```

My data is as follows:

```
const data = [{title: 'Something', costs: '1 million'}]
```

But more of those ;).

I've tried everything I could think of but it seems not to be necessary.
In the end I need a list of checkboxes which shows the name and how much it will cost behind it (e.g. Pizza ($1,50))

Hope somebody knows a solution (or google search option, I cant find anybody else with this issue but maybe I'm using the wrong terminology)

Comment: is `label={`${item.title} (${item.costs})`}` not working?

Comment: Thanks so much, I wasnt aware of this option. It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

```
label={`${item.title} (${item.costs})`}
```

Comment: I was not aware of this option, thanks so much. It works like a charm!